# ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "drupal_cache_block_pkey"

Tags: 7, caching

Using Drupal 7.19 and standard Bartik theme [at my site](http://preferans.de) (in Russian language, UTF8 encoding) with PostgreSQL 8.4.13 and pgbouncer on CentOS 6.3 / 64 bit Linux I keep getting these kind of error messages in the database log files at `/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_log/postgresql-*.log`:

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "drupal_cache_block_pkey"
STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO drupal_cache_block (cid, serialized, created, expire, data) VALUES ('user:new:bartik:ru:r.1', '1', '1359635697', '-1', 'a:2:{s:7:"subject";s:35:"\\320\\235\\320\\276\\320\\262\\321\\213\\320\\265 \\320\\277\\320\\276\\320\\273\\321\\214\\320\\267\\320\\276\\320\\262\\320\\260\\321\\202\\320\\265\\320\\273\\320\\270";s:7:"content";s:1264:"<div class="item-list"><ul><li class="first"><a href="/user/24331" title="\\320\\230\\320\\275\\321\\204\\320\\276\\321\\200\\320\\274\\320\\260\\321\\206\\320\\270\\321\\217 \\320\\276 \\320\\277\\320\\276\\320\\273\\321\\214\\320\\267\\320\\276\\320\\262\\320\\260\\321\\202\\320\\265\\320\\273\\320\\265." class="username">\\320\\241\\320\\260\\320\\275\\320\\265\\320\\272141</a></li>\\012<li><a href="/user/24330" title="\\320\\230\\320\\275\\321\\204\\320\\276\\321\\200\\320\\274\\320\\260\\321\\206\\320\\270\\321\\217 \\320\\276 \\320\\277\\320\\276\\320\\273\\321\\214\\320\\267\\320\\276\\320\\262\\320\\260\\321\\202\\320\\265\\320\\273\\320\\265." class="username">vetall</a></li>\\012<li><a href="/user/24329" title="\\320\\230\\320\\275\\321\\204\\320\\276\\321\\200\\320\\274\\320\\260\\321\\206\\320\\270\\321\\217 \\320\\276 \\320\\277\\320\\276\\320\\273\\321\\214\\320\\267\\320\\276\\320\\262\\320\\260\\321\\202\\320\\265\\320\\273\\320\\265." class="username">Karina</a></li>\\012<li><a href="/user/24327" title="\\320\\230\\320\\275\\321\\204\\320\\276\\321\\200\\320\\274\\320\\260\\321\\206\\320\\270\\321\\217 \\320\\276 \\320\\277\\320\\276\\320\\273\\321\\214\\320\\267\\320\\276\\320\\262\\320\\260\\321\\202\\320\\265\\320\\273\\320\\265." class="username">sosoia47</a></li>\\012<li><a href="/user/24326" title="\\320\\230\\320\\275\\321\\204\\320\\276\\321\\200\\320\\274\\320\\260\\321\\206\\320\\270\\321\\217 \\320\\276 \\320\\277\\320\\276\\320\\273\\321\\214\\320\\267\\320\\276\\320\\262\\320\\260\\321\\202\\320\\265\\320\\273\\320\\265." class="username">DD</a></li>\\012<li><a href="/user/24324" title="\\320\\230\\320\\275\\321\\204\\320\\276\\321\\200\\320\\274\\320\\260\\321\\206\\320\\270\\321\\217 \\320\\276 \\320\\277\\320\\276\\320\\273\\321\\214\\320\\267\\320\\276\\320\\262\\320\\260\\321\\202\\320\\265\\320\\273\\320\\265." class="username">altabay</a></li>\\012<li><a href="/user/24323" title="\\320\\230\\320\\275\\321\\204\\320\\276\\321\\200\\320\\274\\320\\260\\321\\206\\320\\270\\321\\217 \\320\\276 \\320\\277\\320\\276\\320\\273\\321\\214\\320\\267\\320\\276\\320\\262\\320\\260\\321\\202\\320\\265\\320\\273\\320\\265." class="username">\\320\\235\\320\\265\\321\\200\\320\\262</a></li>\\012<li><a href="/user/24318" title="\\320\\230\\320\\275\\321\\204\\320\\276\\321\\200\\320\\274\\320\\260\\321\\206\\320\\270\\321\\217 \\320\\276 \\320\\277\\320\\276\\320\\273\\321\\214\\320\\267\\320\\276\\320\\262\\320\\260\\321\\202\\320\\265\\320\\273\\320\\265." class="username">\\320\\220\\320\\271\\320\\261\\320\\276\\320\\273</a></li>\\012<li><a href="/user/24317" title="\\320\\230\\320\\275\\321\\204\\320\\276\\321\\200\\320\\274\\320\\260\\321\\206\\320\\270\\321\\217 \\320\\276 \\320\\277\\320\\276\\320\\273\\321\\214\\320\\267\\320\\276\\320\\262\\320\\260\\321\\202\\320\\265\\320\\273\\320\\265." class="username">\\320\\220\\320\\273\\320\\265\\320\\272\\321\\201\\320\\265\\320\\271</a></li>\\012<li class="last"><a href="/user/24316" title="\\320\\230\\320\\275\\321\\204\\320\\276\\321\\200\\320\\274\\320\\260\\321\\206\\320\\270\\321\\217 \\320\\276 \\320\\277\\320\\276\\320\\273\\321\\214\\320\\267\\320\\276\\320\\262\\320\\260\\321\\202\\320\\265\\320\\273\\320\\265." class="username">dejwitxyzsdaweq</a></li>\\012</ul></div>";}')
```

Clearing cache by clicking the button at the `/admin/config/development/performance` doesn't help.

Is there maybe a way to fix that by clearing one of these SQL tables?

```
 public | drupal_cache                          | table | drupal
 public | drupal_cache_block                    | table | drupal
 public | drupal_cache_bootstrap                | table | drupal
 public | drupal_cache_field                    | table | drupal
 public | drupal_cache_filter                   | table | drupal
 public | drupal_cache_form                     | table | drupal
 public | drupal_cache_image                    | table | drupal
 public | drupal_cache_menu                     | table | drupal
 public | drupal_cache_page                     | table | drupal
 public | drupal_cache_path                     | table | drupal
 public | drupal_cache_update                   | table | drupal
```

Does it make sense to submit a bug against Drupal 7?

My config data - **postgresql.conf**:

```
shared_buffers = 4096MB  # I've got 32 GB of RAM to burn
work_mem = 32MB
wal_buffers = 4MB
checkpoint_segments = 32
escape_string_warning = off  # otherwise Drupal spams me with warnings
```

and **pgbouncer.ini**:

```
pool_mode = session
server_reset_query = DISCARD ALL;
server_check_delay = 10
max_client_conn = 600
default_pool_size = 50
```

**UPDATE:** Submitted [bug #1907230](http://drupal.org/node/1907230) against Drupal core

Answer (score 1):

This happens when we export/import. I have met this many times what i done to overcome this is to empty the cache tables and retry import.

This will work and i am glad you submitted a bug report.

Comment: I only export (`pg_dump` the drupal database to a text file every night). I've run a `pg_dump` manually to test your idea, but couldn't see new errors in postgresql logfile during/after `pg_dump` running, so I'm actually not sure if the error is related to import/export.